# TimerTrigger Azure Function stuck (doesn't triggered) after change "_master" function key

Tags: azure, function, azure-functions, .net-7.0

I have create an Azure Function (v4, isolated) which uses a TimeTrigger.

My function was fired correctly up to a bad manipulation...

I have try to run my non-http function manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http

Within Azure Portal, I have add a function key (not at the app level) named "_master" with a value generated by Azure.

Since this modification, my function doesn't run... Any idea? How can I cancel this operation? How can I configure Azure to use this key instead of default?

I have try to redeploy my functions, the key aren't modified.
I cannot delete this function app...

Answer (score 1):

> How can I cancel this operation?

I have reproduced the issue at my environment and noticed the following difference-

[image]

If you will create a function key with **_master** name, then function might consider it as master key. So making it un-editable. But the value it contains, doesn't have admin level access. So you will get 401 error.

**Please Note:** In order to invoke the timer trigger function manually, you need master key (App level) because it only has admin level permission, as stated in this [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http).

Comment: Yes, we need to set admin level access to our _master key... (or reset it)

We didn't see any logs in Insights (we don't know if it's a 401 or not) - how did you get your 401 response?

Now we know that we need the app _master key... 

We have tried to redeploy (with tf), functions was deleted while few seconds, but when the function was recreated, the function contains a _master key. I don't know if it's the "original" _master key or if it's "our" generated _master key (we didn't archive it).

Comment: I tried to trigger the function from code+test in portal and got 401 error. When you will create the function app, that time only _master key will get generated and it will have admin level access by default

Comment: We don't need to create _master key as it will get created by default while creating function app itself. You can access this key from App key section

Comment: Finally we have redeploy from scratch our function ; the _master key was restore to an original value, generated by Azure

I think we had replace the _master key and the TimerTrigger could't not start 'cause the keys mismatch between our given _master key and the original _master key

Comment: Yes, to manually trigger the timer trigger function you need master key which is usually gets created during function app creation, as you had created a similar key in function level with a random value, so your function will not get trigger with that key